# Will gravity cause pressure fluid to exit at a faster rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature

Does having a release valve at the top of a pressurized container or bottom of it make any difference to the velocity of the gas exiting at a specified pressure?

I'm confused because gravity is constantly working on every particle near the Earth's surface, so if the gas exits from the bottom, overall velocity will be in the direction of gravity, whereas exiting from the top means going against gravity? Should this make a difference to the gas' velocity, and why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

As in the atmosphere, the pressure in a tank of gas decreases as you go up. The difference will depend on the density of the gas, and is normally quite small.